# Problemas al realizar un menu con subdivisiones en boostrap

Tags: css, bootstrap, css3

Actualmente mi menu esta asi
[image: css]

pero quiero convertirlo a este otro

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi codigo de este menu es el sgt:

```html
 <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->

 <div class="collapse navbar-collapse noMrgLeft " id="navbar-2">

     <ul class="nav navbar-nav menuPrincipalItem">


         <li class="dropdown <?php if ($mn == 1) {
                                    echo 'active';
                                } ?>">

             <a data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle" href="#">Electrodomesticos<b class="caret"></b></a>
             <ul role="menu" class="dropdown-menu">
                 <li><a href="index.html#Listar" onclick="fAjax('ListarProductos.php','&cat=1','div_listado')" target="_parent">Aspiradoras</a></li>
                 <li><a href="index.html#Listar" onclick="fAjax('ListarProductos.php','&cat=2','div_listado')" target="_parent">Ollas arroceras</a></li>
                 <li><a href="index.html#Listar" onclick="fAjax('ListarProductos.php','&cat=3','div_listado')" target="_parent">Batidoras</a></li>
                 <li><a href="index.html#Listar" onclick="fAjax('ListarProductos.php','&cat=4','div_listado')" target="_parent">Cafeteras</a></li>
                 <li><a href="index.html#Listar" onclick="fAjax('ListarProductos.php','&cat=5','div_listado')" target="_parent">Extractoras</a></li>
                 <li><a href="index.html#Listar" onclick="fAjax('ListarProductos.php','&cat=6','div_listado')" target="_parent">Exprimidores</a></li>
                 <li><a href="index.html#Listar" onclick="fAjax('ListarProductos.php','&cat=7','div_listado')" target="_parent">Hervidores</a></li>
                 <li><a href="index.html#Listar" onclick="fAjax('ListarProductos.php','&cat=8','div_listado')" target="_parent">Hornos electricos</a></li>
                 <li><a href="index.html#Listar" onclick="fAjax('ListarProductos.php','&cat=9','div_listado')" target="_parent">Licuadoras</a></li>
                 <li><a href="index.html#Listar" onclick="fAjax('ListarProductos.php','&cat=10','div_listado')" target="_parent">Parrillas</a></li>
                 <li><a href="index.html#Listar" onclick="fAjax('ListarProductos.php','&cat=11','div_listado')" target="_parent">Planchas</a></li>
                 <li><a href="index.html#Listar" onclick="fAjax('ListarProductos.php','&cat=12','div_listado')" target="_parent">Procesadores</a></li>
                 <li><a href="index.html#Listar" onclick="fAjax('ListarProductos.php','&cat=13','div_listado')" target="_parent">Sandwicheras</a></li>
                 <li><a href="index.html#Listar" onclick="fAjax('ListarProductos.php','&cat=14','div_listado')" target="_parent">Sartenes electricas</a></li>
                 <li><a href="index.html#Listar" onclick="fAjax('ListarProductos.php','&cat=15','div_listado')" target="_parent">Vaporeras</a></li>
                 <li><a href="index.html#Listar" onclick="fAjax('ListarProductos.php','&cat=16','div_listado')" target="_parent">Tostadoras</a></li>
                 <li><a href="index.html#Listar" onclick="fAjax('ListarProductos.php','&cat=17','div_listado')" target="_parent">Freidora</a></li>
             </ul>


         </li>

         <li class="dropdown <?php if ($mn == 2) {
                                    echo 'active';
                                } ?>">
             <a data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle" href="#">Linea Blanca<b class="caret"></b></a>
             <ul role="menu" class="dropdown-menu">
                 <li><a href="index.html#Listar" onclick="fAjax('ListarProductos.php','&cat=18','div_listado')" target="_parent">Cocinas</a></li>
                 <li><a href="index.html#Listar" onclick="fAjax('ListarProductos.php','&cat=19','div_listado')" target="_parent">Refrigeradoras</a></li>
                 <li><a href="index.html#Listar" onclick="fAjax('ListarProductos.php','&cat=20','div_listado')" target="_parent">Lavadoras</a></li>
                 <li><a href="index.html#Listar" onclick="fAjax('ListarProductos.php','&cat=21','div_listado')" target="_parent">Secadoras</a></li>
                 <li><a href="index.html#Listar" onclick="fAjax('ListarProductos.php','&cat=22','div_listado')" target="_parent">Campanas Extractoras</a></li>
                 <li><a href="index.html#Listar" onclick="fAjax('ListarProductos.php','&cat=23','div_listado')" target="_parent">Hornos Microondas</a></li>
             </ul>

         </li>

         <li class="dropdown <?php if ($mn == 3) {
                                    echo 'active';
                                } ?>">
             <a data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle" href="#">CUIDADO PERSONAL<b class="caret"></b></a>
             <ul role="menu" class="dropdown-menu">
                 <li><a href="index.html#Listar" onclick="fAjax('ListarProductos.php','&cat=24','div_listado')" target="_parent">Secadores de cabello</a></li>
                 <li><a href="index.html#Listar" onclick="fAjax('ListarProductos.php','&cat=25','div_listado')" target="_parent">Depiladores</a></li>
                 <li><a href="index.html#Listar" onclick="fAjax('ListarProductos.php','&cat=26','div_listado')" target="_parent">Cortadoras de cabello</a></li>
                 <li><a href="index.html#Listar" onclick="fAjax('ListarProductos.php','&cat=27','div_listado')" target="_parent">Alisadoras</a></li>
                 <li><a href="index.html#Listar" onclick="fAjax('ListarProductos.php','&cat=28','div_listado')" target="_parent">Afeitadoras</a></li>
                 <li><a href="index.html#Listar" onclick="fAjax('ListarProductos.php','&cat=29','div_listado')" target="_parent">Rizadores de cabello</a></li>
             </ul>
         </li>




         <li class="dropdown <?php if ($mn == 4) {
                                    echo 'active';
                                } ?>">

             <a data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle" href="#">CLIMATIZACIÓN<b class="caret"></b></a>
             <ul role="menu" class="dropdown-menu">
                 <li><a href="index.html#Listar" onclick="fAjax('ListarProductos.php','&cat=30','div_listado')" target="_parent">Ventiladores</a></li>
                 <li><a href="index.html#Listar" onclick="fAjax('ListarProductos.php','&cat=31','div_listado')" target="_parent">Deshumedecedores</a></li>
                 <li><a href="index.html#Listar" onclick="fAjax('ListarProductos.php','&cat=32','div_listado')" target="_parent">Purificadores</a></li>
                 <li><a href="index.html#Listar" onclick="fAjax('ListarProductos.php','&cat=33','div_listado')" target="_parent">Estufas</a></li>
             </ul>

         </li>

         <li class="dropdown  full-width<?php if ($mn == 5) {
                                            echo 'active';
                                        } ?>">

             <a data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle" href="#">TEGNOLOGÍA<b class="caret"></b></a>
             <ul role="menu" class="dropdown-menu">
                 <li><a href="index.html#Listar" onclick="fAjax('ListarProductos.php','&cat=34','div_listado')" target="_parent">TV-LCD</a></li>
                 <li><a href="index.html#Listar" onclick="fAjax('ListarProductos.php','&cat=35','div_listado')" target="_parent">TV-LED</a></li>
                 <li><a href="index.html#Listar" onclick="fAjax('ListarProductos.php','&cat=36','div_listado')" target="_parent">TV-PLASMA</a></li>
                 <li><a href="index.html#Listar" onclick="fAjax('ListarProductos.php','&cat=37','div_listado')" target="_parent">TV-CRT</a></li>
                 <li><a href="index.html#Listar" onclick="fAjax('ListarProductos.php','&cat=38','div_listado')" target="_parent">Portátil</a></li>
                 <li><a href="index.html#Listar" onclick="fAjax('ListarProductos.php','&cat=39','div_listado')" target="_parent">Blu-ray</a></li>
                 <li><a href="index.html#Listar" onclick="fAjax('ListarProductos.php','&cat=40','div_listado')" target="_parent">DVD</a></li>
                 <li><a href="index.html#Listar" onclick="fAjax('ListarProductos.php','&cat=41','div_listado')" target="_parent">Tablet</a></li>
                 <li><a href="index.html#Listar" onclick="fAjax('ListarProductos.php','&cat=42','div_listado')" target="_parent">Camara</a></li>

             </ul>

         </li>

         <li class="dropdown  full-width<?php if ($mn == 6) {
                                            echo 'active';
                                        } ?>">

             <a data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle" href="#">AUDIO<b class="caret"></b></a>
             <ul role="menu" class="dropdown-menu" id="ayd">
                 <li><a href="index.html#Listar" onclick="fAjax('ListarProductos.php','&cat=43','div_listado')" target="_parent">Radio</a></li>
                 <li><a href="index.html#Listar" onclick="fAjax('ListarProductos.php','&cat=44','div_listado')" target="_parent">Microcomponentes</a></li>
                 <li><a href="index.html#Listar" onclick="fAjax('ListarProductos.php','&cat=45','div_listado')" target="_parent">Radioreloj</a></li>
                 <li><a href="index.html#Listar" onclick="fAjax('ListarProductos.php','&cat=46','div_listado')" target="_parent">MaxSistemaNitro</a></li>
                 <li><a href="index.html#Listar" onclick="fAjax('ListarProductos.php','&cat=47','div_listado')" target="_parent">Minicomponentes</a></li>
                 <li><a href="index.html#Listar" onclick="fAjax('ListarProductos.php','&cat=48','div_listado')" target="_parent">Home Theater</a></li>
                 <li><a href="index.html#Listar" onclick="fAjax('ListarProductos.php','&cat=49','div_listado')" target="_parent">Grabadora digital</a></li>
                 <li><a href="index.html#Listar" onclick="fAjax('ListarProductos.php','&cat=50','div_listado')" target="_parent">Radiograbadores</a></li>
                 <li><a href="index.html#Listar" onclick="fAjax('ListarProductos.php','&cat=51','div_listado')" target="_parent">Subwoofer</a></li>
                 <li><a href="index.html#Listar" onclick="fAjax('ListarProductos.php','&cat=52','div_listado')" target="_parent">Amplificadores</a></li>
             </ul>

         </li>

     </ul>


 </div>

 <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
```

Comment: Qué es lo que has intentado y qué problema tienes?